# Typed Dataset- Enforce Contraint

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, dataset

I am using typed dataset in asp.net 4.5, but when i am filling datatable using tableadapter and dataset i am getting enforce constraint error.

"Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.". In dataset there in only one row still i\I am getting this error . Currently i am using

```
Dataset.EnforceConstraints = false;
```

but i dont want to use this. so please give me solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

this error happened due to constraints in the table. If you are using relations in the table it will happened. ie, your table has a fourign key member, you are not allowing add in the child table without an entry in the master table.[image]

in the image there showed a relation. on table2 a column is fourign key of table1. So if you try to insert a value in table2 without an entry in table with same sl_no this error will be shown.

Comment: +1 for diagram. Also, the issue could be a null value coming from the adapter, either because a column wasn't included in the select, or it's returning a null when the DataSet column definition has a constraint that it cannot be null.

Answer (score 0):

please closely look at TDS. i am sure that your TDS contains multiple P.key fields that does not match with your retrn dateset. so please remove one/some of the P.Key from yours TDS by right clicking on the field. and test again. Hope that it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for your help. I got the solution. On that composite key, i have removed primary constraint and converted it to unique constraint because there was one nullable column. And there was one problem maxlength of one column was less.  I am posting this because it may be useful for someone else in future.

Thanks.